# Convolution of uniform distribution

Tags: convolution, uniform-distribution

I'm a bit confused by this question.

Let X have a uniform distribution on $(-1,1)$ and let Y be independent of X with a uniform distribution over $(-1,1)$. What is the cumulative distribution function of $S=\sqrt{X^2+Y^2}$.

In other words, if you make a move in the X and Y direction (uniformly distributed), what is the distribution of the total distance travelled?

Kind regards

Comment: Well, the chance of being on a certain area on the x-y plane is the area divided by the total area of the square (which is $2\cdot 2 = 4$).
Now, for $S\leq 1$ we can notice that the area of a ring with inner radius $s$ and outer radius $s+ds$ is $2\pi s ds$ which means the probability density function is $\frac{2\pi s}{4} = \frac{\pi}{2} s$. Now for $s\geq 1$, try thinking how this will change because not all of the ring is in the square ;)

Comment: I'm a bit confused by the $S≤1$, since this will always be true. The maximum value S can attain is when both X en Y are 1 or -1, i.e. $S = \sqrt{1^2+1^2} = 1$

Comment: I found this related post, but I'm not sure if this method can be applied here. I tried but failed :-(

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116620/convolution-of-2-uniform-random-variables?rq=1

Comment: $\sqrt{1^2+1^2}=1$?